# SQL Register Form

Tags: python, flask

We are creating a register page using FLASK and we can't seem to figure out how to insert data from the form into the database. We have read the FLASK docs and can't find anything that works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code is printed below (login functions have been removed):

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, g
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

DATABASE = "./database.db"

#Database Functions
def get_db():

    print("get_db RUN")

    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    print("query_db RUN")
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()

    print("rv: ", str(rv))
    cur.close()

    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv

def register_db(username, password, email, date_of_birth):

    print("register_db RUN")

    return query_db("insert into User (username, password, email, date_of_birth) values (?, ?, ?, ?)", [username, password, email, date_of_birth], one=True)

def log_the_user_in(username):
    return render_template("profile.html", username=username)

@app.route("/")
def main_page():
    return render_template("main_page.html")

@app.route("/register", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def register():

    print("register RUN")

    error = None

    if request.method == "POST":

        register_db(request.form["username"], request.form["password"], request.form["email"], request.form["date_of_birth"])

        return render_template("profile.html")

    return render_template("register.html")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: What is wrong with the given code? Does it provide any error message?

Comment: It just goes through to profile.html. I think it might have something to do with committing the changes to the database and I need to use commit().

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem?